# if Not undefined and indexOf ('foo') do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, indexof, typeof

So I'm trying to call where if not undefined and index is foo so I use:

```
if (typeof(getdata(js, 'box1')) != "undefined" 
&& (getdata(js, 'box1')).indexOf('foo') >= 0) {
      // Do something
   }
```

This works fine but I dont want to call the getdata twice. Is there way to say if `getdata` is **not undefined** and the indexOf is foo then do something, without calling the `getdata()` function twice?

Comment: Why are you checking if the return value of a function is undefined?

Comment: The function gets values from localstorage, so sometimes if the users clears its cache, it return undefined. If you dont call that, you get an error

Comment: IMO, you'd be better off catching that in the function and returning null instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative:

```
if (/foo/.test(getdata(js, "box1"))) {
    // do something
}
```

While this allows you to get away with a single check, involving a regular expression for such a simple test could be frowned upon :)

You're better off using a local variable for storing the outcome of the function call:

```
var data = getdata(js, "box1");

if (data && data.indexOf("foo") ==! -1) {
    // do something
}
```

Also note that `typeof` is an operator and not a function:

```
typeof something // instead of typeof(something)
```

Comment: Can I go: "if index.of foo, ELSE IF undefined, do this". Because on the error it seems that it doesn't pass from the indexOf.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
var data = getdata(js, 'box1');
if(typeof(data) != 'undefined' && data.indexOf('foo') >= 0) {

}
```

Comment: It works although I have many same function for different boxes. So I'll need to set a variable for each function? I asked in case there was an easier, less-code solution

Comment: Can you place a class on the boxes? Then you can simply get all the boxes by class and push them into an array and loop over the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the indexOf of the value or an empty string if the value is undefined or null.

```
if ( (getdata(js, 'box1') || '').indexOf('foo') !=-1) {
      // Do something
   }
```

Hopefully your function will only return a string, undefined or null.

Comment: And hopefully it won't return the string '0'